# How to Install OEM USB Drivers for my LYF phone?

Tags: android-sdk

I'm a newbie. Recently, I have installed Android Studio 2 on my PC. Run my first "hello world" project on Emulator. But the Emulator is taking too much time to load. So, I thought I would directly install Apk on my Lyf phone [Model no: LYF_LS4006]. So I checkout this site https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html#Win7.
I don't where to find its drivers. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I have a LYF Phone (LS-4005) which I wanted to connect with Android Studio to debug apps on real phone in place of emulator. So I searched for endless hours on Google Search for correct ADB driver of this phone but didn't get succeed because I was searching at wrong place.

> Google already facilitates developers to download generic USB drivers
>   which are compatible with most of the Android phones through the
>   **Android SDK Manager** itself which comes bundled with Android Studio

Below mentioned are the steps to get the drivers directly from Google.

So here is the step by step guide on how to connect any LYF handset with Android Studio for testing apps on original hardware in place of emulator:

[**Please make sure that your LYF phone is connected with usb as Media device (MTP) before continuing**]

1. Enable USB debugging on your LYF phone (refer to this post for how-to: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html)
2. Open Android Studio and go to SDK Manager (Tools > Android > SDK Manager)
3. Install Google USB Drivers by checking it if it is unchecked and click on Apply button.
4. Once Google USB Drivers are installed, open device manager (click on Start button and type: device manager, click on first search result) and follow these steps:

   - Locate and expand Android Phone (or Unknown Devices) in the right pane.
   - Right-click on Android Composite ADB Interface (or ADB Interface) and select Update Driver. This will launch the Hardware Update Wizard.
   - Select Install from a list or specific location and click Next.
   - Select Search for the best driver in these locations; uncheck Search removable media; and check Include this location in the search.
   - Click Browse and then locate the USB driver folder. For example, the Google USB Driver is located in C:\Users\{user}\android-sdks\extras\google\usb_driver. where {user} is your Windows User name.
   - Click Next to install the driver.

Now after installation is successful, you will see a prompt on yout LYF phone asking for permission to 'Allow USB debugging' request from computer. Simply accept it by clicking on 'ok' button and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

LYF phones are basically developed by Chinese manufacturer named ZTE (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LYF#Production) So try choosing ZTE OEM's USB drivers for LYF handset. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Please add links to ZTE Drivers.

Comment: @GokulNC you shall try my second solution I posted below. Installing default usb drivers provided by Google has worked for me like a charm. Don't forget to upvote the answer you found helpful ;)

Answer (score 0):

@RahulDhangar gave a great answer to this post but in case if you would like to read official post by Google developers on this topic, here are the links to consider:

- https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html
- https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html

Again, this post also shows some useful tips to follow on the same topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947834/how-to-test-android-apps-in-a-real-device-with-android-studio

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Anjali. This does not suffices as an answer but more of a comment. Link only answers become unhelpful once the link dies. Even Google's older links can give 404. Please [edit] and mention the relevant info in your post.

Comment: Thanks @Firelord for pointing this out. I will definitely keep it in mind while answering questions next time.